# Interpreting the results of time profiler and activity monitor

Tags: profiling, benchmarking, instruments

For a research project I had to modify a Titanium application such that it can be run in Cordova too. Now that both versions of the app are working as expected, my last task is to do some benchmarking in order to compare the Titanium version with the Cordova version.

We would like to compare CPU usage, memory usage, communication speed, etc.
What i had in mind is :

- Do some profiling on both versions with Xcode
- Export instrument data to CSV file
- Import the CSV files in a statistical program (SPSS)
- Compare both versions by drawing graphs, using boxplots, etc.

Currently, i did the profiling on both versions using the activity monitor instrument and the time profiler instrument.

However, i feel like the data i am exporting to a CSV file is meaningless, or at least i don't understand which values are meaningful to compare.

*For example with the CPU usage, I would like to export the percentages of CPU my app is consuming in each time interval such that I can import them into SPSS and compute the mean CPU usage, draw graphs, make boxplots, etc. However, in the "sample list" of the time profiler no CPU usage percentage is associated with each time interval.*

Hence, **my question is, if I want to do a simple comparison between both versions of my app for at least CPU usage and memory usage, which values of the time profiler and activity manager are useful to me and what do they mean?**

PS : I asked my promotor but he could not help me..

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Run `instruments` from the command line or use the Instruments app - former option e.g.:

`instruments -l 10000 -t 'Activity Monitor' -w 'DEVICE_UDID' YOUR_APP.app`

2. Use [InstrumentsParser](https://github.com/powerli/InstrumentsParser) to produce a JSON containing time slices/performance data from the binary files produced in Step 1.
3. Mangle the produced JSON in Step 2. and feed it for further analysis

The JSON output in Step 2. contains e.g. `ResidentSize` which is the `Real Mem` column in Instruments app and `CPUUsage` which is the `% CPU` column.